# SQLite avoiding duplicate entries

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I haven't used SQLite before. As far as I remember, when I was using MySQL, if I create a constraint with the option of `UNIQUE` I would not receive any errors if I try to add a duplicate element.

It seems like that's not the case for SQLite.

This is how I create my Table:

```
    // Create table for Wi-Fi Information
    myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + WIFI_DATABASE_TABLE
            + " (WifiName VARCHAR UNIQUE);");
```

This is how I insert elements

```
    if (tab == DBTable.WIFI_DATABASE) {
        myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + WIFI_DATABASE_TABLE
                + " (WifiName)" + SQLValues + ";");
    }
```

My problem is when I insert the same element I am getting `Column WifiName name not unique (code 19)` error. What I want is simply not to see any errors. How can I do that without playing around with catching exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

Specify conflict resolution so that the operation doesn't fail and no exception is thrown:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ...;
```

[Reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)

Comment: Is `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` Part should be entered at the very last or  next to the constraint?

Comment: The `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` is the syntax that could be used when specifying constraints in table creation. For inserts it's "OR IGNORE" . Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for conflict resolution on an `INSERT` is to use `OR IGNORE`

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ...
```

More info: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html